# Conditional statement for the last occurrence of an AMPScript loop

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, loop

I'm trying to remove the border only for the last time **[content]** shows up in a loop. A user can have anywhere from 1 to 3 rows showing. How would I set a conditional statement just for the last occurrence in an AMPScript loop?

```
%%[
var @rs, @row, @cntr, @link
SET @rs = LookupRows("S1", "S2", S3)

for @cntr = 1 to ROWCOUNT(@rs) do
    SET @row = Row(@rs, @cntr)
]%%

    **[content]**

    %%[IF  ROWCOUNT(@rs) == 0  then]%%

    %%[ENDIF]%%  

%%[next @cntr]%%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track.  Something like this, perhaps?

```
%%[

var @rs, @row, @cntr, @link
SET @rs = LookupRows("S1", "S2", S3)

for @cntr = 1 to ROWCOUNT(@rs) do

    SET @row = Row(@rs, @cntr)

]%%

    %%[ IF @cntr < ROWCOUNT(@rs) then ]%%

        [content]   

    %%[ ELSE ]%%

        [content displayed on last iteration]

    %%[ ENDIF ]%%  

%%[ next @cntr ]%%
```